Messagebird NuGet Package 3.2.0: Recipients Object Not Returning Correct Structure in C#
I am using the Messagebird NuGet package (version 3.2.0) to send SMS messages in a C# application. According to the Messagebird documentation, the expected structure of the recipients object in the API response should look like this:
"recipients":{
    "totalCount": 1,
    "totalSentCount": 1,
    "totalDeliveredCount": 0,
    "totalDeliveryFailedCount": 0,
    "items": [
        {
            "recipient": 31612345678,
            "status": "sent",
            "statusDatetime": "2016-05-03T14:26:57+00:00"
        }
    ]
}

However, when I use the NuGet package to make the API call, the recipients object in the response only contains a list of msisdns instead of the detailed structure shown above:
"recipients":["012345679"]
To confirm that the API itself is working correctly, I tested the same API call using Postman, and I received the full, valid recipients object as documented.
Steps I've Tried

Verified that I am using NuGet package version 3.2.0.

Tested the API call using Postman and confirmed that the API returns the correct structure.

Checked the Messagebird documentation to ensure I am expecting the correct format.


Question
Why does the Messagebird NuGet package (3.2.0) return only msisdns in the recipients object instead of the full detailed structure as per the documentation? Is there a known issue with the library, or am I missing some configuration or steps?
Additional Information

NuGet Package: Messagebird 3.2.0

API Call Method: Sending SMS

Testing Tool: Postman (for validation)

Language: C#


Any insights or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!

The issue arises because the serialization process can sometimes alter the structure of the recipients object due to tightly coupled binding in C#. This behavior might occur when you use a strongly-typed class or rely on serialization/deserialization processes without verifying the raw API response.
Steps to Resolve

Double-Check the API Response:
Ensure that you are examining the raw API response before it undergoes serialization. Use tools like Postman or log the response as a plain JSON string.

Avoid Premature Serialization:
If you serialize the response object using JsonConvert.SerializeObject() or similar methods, the structure might change due to how the object model is defined.

Define Strongly-Typed Classes:
Create a strongly-typed class that matches the expected structure of the recipients object. For example:
public class RecipientItem
{
 public long Recipient { get; set; }
 public string Status { get; set; }
 public DateTime StatusDatetime { get; set; }
}

public class Recipients
{
  public int TotalCount { get; set; }
  public int TotalSentCount { get; set; }
  public int TotalDeliveredCount { get; set; }
  public int TotalDeliveryFailedCount { get; set; }
  public List<RecipientItem> Items { get; set; }
}


Bind the Response to the Strongly-Typed Class:
Deserialize the API response directly into the strongly-typed class. For example:
 var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(apiUrl);
 var jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 var recipients = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Recipients>(jsonResponse);



By explicitly defining and binding to a strongly-typed class, you can ensure the structure is preserved correctly and matches the documented API response.
